# Is a screen mandatory for using remote desktop?

Tags: linux, vnc, remote-control

I'd like to use the GUI environment on a spare box I have headless, not just ssh into it.

Is it possible to setup a remote desktop service even when there's no screen attached to the remote host?

I'm intending to use Debian Linux on the host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, the only thing to be aware of is if you do not have a monitor you also may not have a mouse or keyboard. Some BIOS's will throw a error if it detects no keyboard connected but that can usually be disabled. It is just something you need to be aware of.

The Unix Stack Exchange site has a good question and answer on [SSH X forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine) that may help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still run a GUI with no monitor attached.  Additionally, you can X forward or VNC share or whatever from it.

Answer (score 1):

[Xvnc](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/xvnc.html) is a virtual X server that provides VNC remote desktop service. No monitor (or even video card) is required for it to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you use VNC, you will need a graphics card, but no monitor or keyboard.

Comment: With a graphics card it's easiest to set up, but you could also use `Xvfb` which can run X without a graphics card at all. (But computers without *any* graphics capability are very, very rare these days).